# How can I automate code to plot a line between two points?

Tags: python, math, algebra

Currently trying to create an automated function that can find a line between two points. Tried testing this function (by plotting) but when I plot the function I get a 'v-shaped' line. What changes can I make to complete this function? Thanks.

```
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     from math import e

     x = [0, 9]
     y = [7, 2]
     m = (y[1]-x[1])/(y[0]-x[0])
     b = m*(y[0]-x[0])+x[1]

     for i in range (-10, 10):
      prob_x = m*i + b

      x.append(i)
      y.append(prob_x)

     plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "finding" a line. Did you mean that you want to *interpolate* between the beginning and end values? Also, did you try *actually checking the values* in `x` and `y`? Do you know what they should be? If not, it seems that your question is purely about math, not about writing code.

Comment: That said: think carefully about what each variable in your program represents. For example, I assume that `m` is intended to represent the *slope* of the line, yes? So that formula is rise over run, yes? Does `y[1]-x[1]` make sense for the rise? Why or why not? Does `y[0]-x[0]` make sense for the run? Why or why not? There are other issues. You should try to [find them yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 9]
y = [7, 2]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

You don't need to do anything, plt.plot returns a line between two points anyway

Output:

[image]